# R - using wildcard in file.rename path

Tags: r

I cannot figure out the syntax for this.  I want to simply rename the following by replacing the ".sql.sql763286" with ".txt":

I want this:

```
C:/Documents and Settings/jdoe/Desktop/ealleip.sql.sql763286
```

to be:

```
C:/Documents and Settings/jdoe/Desktop/ealleip.txt
```

I've tried all kinds of syntax that I found on Google, Rfunctions, etc. etc.  I even tried the basic:

```
file.rename ( 'C:/Documents and Settings/jdoe/Desktop/ealleip*', 'C:/Documents and   Settings/jdoe/Desktop/ealleip.txt')
```

Nothing works.

Can anyone help me?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's not working?  What's the error message?

Comment: Thanks for responding.  I'm working in a 3rd party software that has an R "Tool".  It doesn't error out, it just doesn't rename it.  So when I try: file.rename(

'C:/Documents and Settings/jdoe/Desktop/ealleip.sql.sql7863286'

,

'C:/Documents and Settings/jdoe/Desktop/ealleip.txt'

) it works fine, but when I replace the .sql.sql763286 with an asterisk, it doesn't error out, but yet it doesn't perform the funtion.

Comment: The string "Nothing works" is not a built-in error message in R. [What, specifically, have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: I don't think you can use wildcards in that function. You probably want to use `dir` which has a regexp compliant `pattern` argument, and then using `sub` on that to get the correct input to put into `file.rename`

Comment: I've tried file.rename('C:/Documents and Settings/mbarone/Desktop/+^["ealleip"]','C:/Documents and Settings/mbarone/Desktop/ealleip.txt').  I do not get an error, but it doesn't rename the file.  However, if I do the simple file.rename('C:/Documents and Settings/mbarone/Desktop/ealeip.sql.sql763286','C:/Documents and Settings/mbarone/Desktop/ealleip.txt'), then it renames it.  So I must not be handling the wildcard correctly. I've tried several different variations for ^["ealleip"], trying to figure out what the correct syntax would be for a wildcard after ealleip.

Comment: Thanks James, I'll research that.

Answer (score 0):

```
file.rename(from = paste0("C:/Documents and Settings/jdoe/Desktop/",list.files(path = "C:/Documents and Settings/jdoe/Desktop", pattern = "ealleip"), to = "C:/Documents and Settings/jdoe/Desktop/ealleip.txt")
```